# MYSQL Union from left and right and group

Tags: mysql, union

I have a forum with two tables `forum_posts` and `forum_replies`. I need to get the most active users. Here is what I recently tried

```
                SELECT forum_reply.added_by, forum_posts.added_by FROM forum_reply  LEFT JOIN   forum_posts     ON  forum_posts.added_by = forum_reply.added_by 
                UNION 
                SELECT forum_posts.added_by, forum_reply.added_by FROM forum_posts  RIGHT JOIN   forum_reply    ON  forum_reply.added_by = forum_posts.added_by 

                WHERE forum_reply.date_added < '".$now."' AND forum_reply.date_added > '".$past24h."' AND forum_posts.date_added < '".$now."' AND forum_posts.date_added > '".$past24h."'

                GROUP BY forum_reply.added_by, forum_posts.added_by ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5");
```

The problem is this query gives me only one result instead of 5. And the result is definitely not real because the user this query gives me haven't posted anything for the last 24 hours.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Except for the `LEFT` / `RIGHT` join, the 1st and 2nd `SELECT` statements in your `UNION` look identical. Why are you doing this `UNION`?

Comment: Well that was really not what I was willing to do. However After I fixed it the results are the same o_O